# unable to understand find method works in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am a `jquery` beginner. I made a table below in html:

[image]

What I wanted to do was - show three alert boxes back to back for 3 checkboxes being found in my table so I did this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#but").click(function(){
        $(".tabclass td").each(function(i){
            if($(this).find("input[type='checkbox']")){
                alert("found");
            }
        });

    });
});
```

But instead I got 9 alert boxes. How can I navigate to `td`s which contains checkboxes only.

HTML CODE:

```
<table border="1" class="tabclass">
    <tr>
        <th>select</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectCheck" class="select" id="ch1" value="1"/> </td>
        <td>Nitin</td>
        <td><select>
            <option>Gurgaon</option>
            <option>Noida</option>
            <option>Rohini</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectCheck" class="select" id="ch2" value="2"/> </td>
        <td>Abc</td>
        <td><select>
            <option>Gurgaon</option>
            <option>Noida</option>
            <option>Rohini</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectCheck" class="select" id="ch3" value="3"/> </td>
        <td>Xyz</td>
        <td><select>
            <option>Gurgaon</option>
            <option>Noida</option>
            <option>Rohini</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<button id="but">Test</button>
```

Comment: can you share the html code

Comment: @rushil I have shared html code now.

Comment: Thanks....Only one change is needed in your code...i have added answer, please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use length to test if element is present, right now you are testing `if(object)` which returns always true

```
if($(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").length){
   alert("found");
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#but").click(function() {
    $(".tabclass td").each(function(i) {
      if ($(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").length) {
        alert("found");
      }
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class="tabclass">
  <th>select</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Address</th>
  <tr>
    <td class='check_cell'>
      <input type="checkbox" name="selectCheck" class="select" id="ch1" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>Nitin</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>Gurgaon</option>
        <option>Noida</option>
        <option>Rohini</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='check_cell'>
      <input type="checkbox" name="selectCheck" class="select" id="ch2" value="2" />
    </td>
    <td>Abc</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>Gurgaon</option>
        <option>Noida</option>
        <option>Rohini</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='check_cell'>
      <input type="checkbox" name="selectCheck" class="select" id="ch3" value="3" />
    </td>
    <td>Xyz</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>Gurgaon</option>
        <option>Noida</option>
        <option>Rohini</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<button id="but">Test</button>
```

or try the `is()` function

```
 if($(this).find('input').is("input[type='checkbox']")){
       alert("found");
    }
```

Comment: This is bassicaly a copy of my answer. Except the `length` part which is not really necessary.

Comment: @Ionut in an alternative universe maybe, here not :))

Comment: That's right. He he, I already knew that, just missed it, fellow compatriot.

Comment: @madalinivascu and lonut thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Change your script to :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#but").click(function(){
          $(".select").each(function(i){
              if($(this).find("input[type='checkbox']")){
                  alert("found");
              }
          });

      });
  });
```

There are 3 td in each tabclass so you get alert 3*3=9 times as you have used each function. so change your selector to your class

just change

```
tabclass td
```

to

```
select
```